# Vuetify - Add loading layer overlay on click event

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new to Laravel and Vuetify. I am looking for a way in Vuetify to add an overlay layer over the page on a click event, eg. Save, Edit, Delete, etc... with a progress icon as per https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/progress#examples. Its only so the user is aware that it is working and not try to repeat clicking the button again. I can't seem to find any Vuetify documentation on how to add overlay layer. Anyone can point me to the right documentation or website?

I am thinking somewhere along the example in this link https://pygmyslowloris.github.io/vue-full-loading/. However, I am unable to install or use any external library so it must be native Vuetify/VueJS. Thanks and I hope my description is clear.

Comment: There aren't any "layers" on a web page per se, you're probably looking to do something like add a `visible` class to the loader on a click event, and  setting some corresponding CSS rules. What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried any but someone pointed out a this site that may be what I needed. https://github.com/PygmySlowLoris/vue-full-loading?ref=madewithvuejs.com

I haven't tried it as I don't really understand the structure of Laravel + VueJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to do this is with css, using a combination of absolute positioning, visibility control, and z-index.  No vue.js magic required.

Your css might look something like this.  Assign the appropriate class to the outer div of your overlay.

```
.popup-visible {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    visibility: visible;
}

.popup-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I am relatively new to Laravel + VueJS, barely 3 days. First, I don't even know where the main CSS file is located. Second, I don't even know how to implement this in the .vue file. I know it sounds pathetic but this framework was force onto me and the original developer works remotely and was not much help and hard to contact.

Comment: @AllieSyadiqin that makes the question a bit too broad. Here's a great free laravel course for beginners: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018 and https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017

Answer (score 8):

You could do this with a fullscreen v-dialog and a progress component inside.

Like this:

```
<v-dialog v-model="loading" fullscreen full-width>
  <v-container fluid fill-height style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);">
    <v-layout justify-center align-center>
      <v-progress-circular
        indeterminate
        color="primary">
      </v-progress-circular>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</v-dialog>
```

And then when @click occurs:

```
loading = true;
```

And when loading is done:

```
loading = false;
```